# Member is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I started writing a simple script but when I start it, a cmd has an error, with thig msg `member not found`

````
  const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#0099ff')
  .setTitle('Felhasználó Infók!')
  .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}))
  .addFields(
  {name:'❯Felhaszáló azonosítód', value: `${message.author.id}` },
  
  ('❯ Ekkor csatlakoztál a szerverre:', moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'))
  )
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter("Jó játékot!");
  message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  }```
````

Comment: You haven't any variable with the name `member`

Comment: `message.member.joinedAt`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do either `message.member` (author) or `message.mentions.members` (people who were mentioned). Try replacing `member.joinedAt` with `message.mentions.members[0].joinedAt`or `message.member.joinedAt`.